# Print a big number

Tags: assembly, overflow, mips

I have this code:

```
addi $t0, $0, 4294967295
addi $v0, $0, 1 
addi $a0, $t0, 0

syscall
```

How can I print out the number `4294967295` here?

Answer (score 0):

If available, use syscall #36 which is `print unsigned`.
Otherwise, convert the number to string yourself.